Cant figure how to parse Response from Chatgpt Open AI
I am using Chatgpt Open AI,
The response that i am getting is


type here
"
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-99AlOqEW1qLw8CaTYVJ2Pnow2JBql",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1711973354,
  "model": "gpt-4-0125-preview",
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": "```json\n{\n  \"Title\": \"Quarterly Report Generation Issue\",\n  \"IssueType\": \"Software\",\n  \"Summary\": \"Software crashes with error 0x846F when generating Q1 2024 financial report.\",\n  \"Response\": {\n    \"Acknowledgement\": \"Hello Marx, we acknowledge the issue with generating the quarterly financial reports and understand the inconvenience it has caused.\",\n    \"Solution\": \"As a temporary measure, please try to generate the report in a different format or use a web version if available. We will provide a comprehensive solution shortly.\"\n  }\n}\n```"
      },
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 318,
    "completion_tokens": 119,
    "total_tokens": 437
  },
  "system_fingerprint": "fp_a7daf7c51e"
} 

The prompt which i passed is
"I will give you a text ok. I want you to generate a response in object json. Keep the content inside the choices array in pure json. Respoonse should include  - 1)Generating a title for this text in 4-5 words 2)Classify this text according the issue types i.e IssueType = "Network" or "Software", "Hardware" or "Security" or "Compatibility" or "Data" or "Performance" or "Maintenance" 3) Generate a short summary of the issue faced in this text in 10-14 words 4) I need a good response in a way Support team responds i.e Acknowledging the issue  + Providing a temporary solution. Keep both Acknowledgement and solution compact and short.Take care that the response should not ask them additional contact , just tell them we will respond to you shortly.
The text is 'The issue I'm facing is with generating quarterly financial reports. When I
attempt to run the report for Q1 2024, the software freezes and eventually
crashes, displaying an error message stating "Error Code 0x846F: Report
Generation Failure." I have tried restarting the software, rebooting my
computer, and checking for updates, but the problem persists.
I understand that this may be an uncommon issue and appreciate your prompt
attention to it. Please let me know if you require any additional information or
if there are specific troubleshooting steps I should follow to assist you
further.
Regards,
Marx'
"`
The swagger code for custom connector is
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: ChatGpt
  description: ''
  version: '1.0'
host: api.openai.com
basePath: /
schemes:
  - https
consumes: []
produces: []
paths:
  /v1/chat/completions:
    post:
      responses:
        default:
          description: default
          schema: {}
      summary: GetResponse
      operationId: GetResponse
      parameters:
        - name: Content-Type
          in: header
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              model:
                type: string
                description: model
              messages:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    role:
                      type: string
                      description: role
                    content:
                      type: string
                      description: content
                description: messages
              temperature:
                type: number
                format: float
                description: temperature
definitions: {}
parameters: {}
responses: {}
securityDefinitions: {}
security:
  - API Key: []
tags: []

I am doing all of this in Power Automate.
I tried parsing the json , through which i got content , which looks like this
```json
{
  "Title": "Quarterly Report Generation Issue",
  "IssueType": "Software",
  "Summary": "Software crashes with error 0x846F when generating Q1 2024 financial report.",
  "Response": {
    "Acknowledgement": "Hello Marx, we acknowledge the issue with generating the quarterly financial reports and understand the inconvenience it has caused.",
    "Solution": "As a temporary measure, please try to generate the report in a different format or use a web version if available. We will provide a comprehensive solution shortly."
  }
}

**Afterwards , i tried replacing the '```json' , which gave me this** ,

json
{
"Title": "Quarterly Report Generation Issue",
"IssueType": "Software",
"Summary": "Software crashes with error 0x846F when generating Q1 2024 financial report.",
"Response": {
"Acknowledgement": "Hello Marx, we acknowledge the issue with generating the quarterly financial reports and understand the inconvenience it has caused.",
"Solution": "As a temporary measure, please try to generate the report in a different format or use a web version if available. We will provide a comprehensive solution shortly."
}
}
**which is not json i suppose **



I just need to understand what '```json' is ? I am using gpt-4-0125-preview , and some way of getting a better response , which can be parsed and Title,IssueType,Summary,Response can be retrieved. 


Try giving an example in the prompt, this helped me when I ask for answer in  json format.

You are a xxx assistance that will help user answer questions from the
Documents. Do not make up answers. Cite the source and please reply as
{{"answer": answer, "source": section title}'.


I used below this format

You're a Text classifier , Text summarizer and Sentiment analyzer. Do not make up answers. Cite the given text and please reply in the following format
{
"subject":{"type":"string","description":"A short title in 4-5 words"},
"summary":{"type":"string","description":"A short summary in 15-20 words"}
"sentiment": {"type": "string", "enum": ["positive", "neutral", "negative"]},}

But it still gives '```json' in the content property
